# Psychic game: CompChoice var never changes

Tags: javascript, function

**My first real js program. I am creating the classic psychic game.  I have an html file with a js file link to it.  PROBLEM: The computer  always chooses the same letter as if it is caught in a function loop and the 'computerGuess' var is not being reassigned after a win or loss--it remains the same.**
    //Values are set
    lettersIndex = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
    'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

```
wins = 0;
losses = 0;
guessesSoFar = []; // this is an array value
guessesLeft = 9;


// computer chooses a letter and it is assigned a variable name
var computerCurrentChoice = lettersIndex[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
lettersIndex.length)];
console.log(" 1 computerCurrentChoice " + computerCurrentChoice);

//Computer picks a letter and gets stored as computerChoice
var runLoop = function () { // ELIMINATING THE FUNCTION HAD NO EFFECT ON 
PROGRAM WORKABILITY



// when User presses key it launches a function to execute process
document.onkeyup = function (event) {

    //when user preses letter key it is stored as var userGuess
    var userGuess = event.key;
    console.log("userGuess      " + userGuess);

    // If the user and the computer choose the same letter: 
    // wins adds 1, 
    // guessesLeft is reset to 9, 
    //guessesSoFar logs the letter choice into array
    //alert is launched notifying user of win
    if (userGuess === computerCurrentChoice) {
        wins++;
        guessesLeft = 9;
        guessesSoFar = [];
        alert("You won!!!");

        // if userGuess and computerChoice are different: 
        // guessesLeft decreases 1, 
        //guessesSoFar logs the letter choice into array
    }

    if (userGuess != computerCurrentChoice) {
        guessesLeft--;
        guessesSoFar.push(userGuess);

        // if guesses left reached 0:
        //alert is launched notifying user of loss
        // guessesLeft and guessesSoFar are reset to 10 and 0 respectively,
        // losses adds 1

        if (guessesLeft < 1) {
            alert("You lose!");
            guessesLeft = 9;
            guessesSoFar = [];
            losses++;
        }
    }
    // Rewrites the html with updated values
    document.getElementById('wins').innerHTML = "Wins: " + wins;
    document.getElementById('losses').innerHTML = "Losses: " + losses;
    document.getElementById('guessesLeft').innerHTML = "Guesses Left: " + 
       guessesLeft;
    document.getElementById('guessesSoFar').innerHTML = "Guesses So Far: " + 
       guessesSoFar;

    console.log(" 2 computerCurrentChoice " + computerCurrentChoice);
 }
 }

  runLoop(); // ELIMINATING THE FUNCTION HAD NO EFFECT ON PROGRAM 
   WORKABILITY
```

Comment: You do not update `computerCurrentChoice` variable when button is pressed. Its value was calculated only once before `runLoop` and never updates. I believe, you know what to do to fix that.

Comment: @ghaiklor is 100% right, you need to update the value, it will always remain the same if you don't update it.

Comment: Yes!  Thank you.  Game works perfectly!  Much obliged.